# How do i render detail template on the same page as category template Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-templates

I am interested in displaying the detail template on the same page as the category template so that when a category is clicked its content(models) is displayed beside it.

something like this

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFYbU.png)

Currently the detail template is rendered independently after clicking a category link.

The models

```
class Category(models.Model):

  cat_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.cat_name

  def get_models(self):
      return Role_model.objects.filter(category=self)


class Role_model(models.Model):


  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name ='categories')
  #photos = models.ImageField(upload_to ='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank = True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length  = 200, blank = False)
  importers = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)


  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Views.py

```
 def categories(request):
    cats = Category.objects.all()

    models = Role_model.objects.all()

    return render(request, "category.html", {'cats':cats,'models':models})



 def DetailView(request, cat_id):

    #cat = get_object_or_404(Category, id = id)

    return render(request,"detail.html", {'category':Category.objects.get(id = cat_id)})
```

urls

## url(r'^$', views.categories, name='categories'),

## url(r'^celebs/(?P\d+)/$', views.DetailView, name='detail'),

Category.html

```
<div class="categories">
{% for category in cats %}
  <ul class = "breadcrumb">
    <li><a href = "celebs/{{category.id}}/">{{category.cat_name}}</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Detail.html

```
<div class="content">

    {% for model in  category.get_models %}
    <h5><a href = "#">{{model.name}}</a></h5>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```